# my android code for creating and using the menu does not work as it should

Tags: android, android-menu

I am a new bee to *Android App Development*. I am practicing the code in the Book *Hello, Android* . Right now I am struck with *Menu* and could not able to move further. I would like to present my situation in clear so that I could be guided by an experienced *android app developer* . I uploaded a picture showing the status.
when I pressed the **menu** I could able to find one option called **settings.**

But nothing happens when the **settings** button is pressed. I am surprised about the error and wasted lot of time to fix it. but I could not able to fix it. I want some real android app development professional to find the solution to this problem that I face and help me to proceed further.

[image]

here is the code that i used.

**test/src/org/anil/test/TestActivity.java**

```
    package org.anil.test;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsMenuSelected( MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.settings:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
    }
```

**test/res/layout/main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**test/src/org/anil/test/Prefs.java**

```
    package org.anil.test;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

    public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

    }
```

**test/res/menu/menu.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings_label"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/settings_shortcut" />
    </menu>
```

**test/res/xml/settings.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 

    <CheckBoxPreference 
    android:key="music"
    android:title="@string/music_title"
    android:summary="@string/music_summary" 
    android:defaultValue="true" />

    <CheckBoxPreference 
    android:key="hints"
    android:title="@string/hints_title"
    android:summary="@string/hints_summary" 
    android:defaultValue="true"/>

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

**test/res/values/strings.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, TestActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Test</string>
    <string name="settings_label">Settings</string>
    <string name="settings_title">Sudoku Settings</string>
    <string name="settings_shortcut">s</string>
    <string name="music_title">Music</string>
    <string name="music_summary">play background music</string>
    <string name="hints_title">Hints</string>
    <string name="hints_summary">Show hints during play</string>

    </resources>
```

**test/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.anil.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Prefs" android:label="@string/settings_title">
    </activity>

    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: You forgot to add menu.xml :) and are you able to see anything in logcat?

Comment: @Hmm: Prefs class has already been posted.

Comment: @ Adil Soomro - Thanks for pointing me out about the absence of menu.xml, now I updated it. By the way I do not know much about the logcat, but I found it at the bottom and tried to open it. I could see, Level-D,Time-06-16,PID 23732,Application ,Tag- BatteryService, Text- Update Start, and after few seconds the values of Tag and Text are changing

Comment: @Adil- Now I found a big list in the logcat what is that? How could this information be used?

Comment: does your application crashes?

Comment: what are the signs of application crashing? when i run the application in the phone, the application starts up normally, even if i use some buttons to start the Pref.class it works well, but only in case when i am using the menus, it does nothing, i could not able to figure out where the error was, i tied in all the possible ways to debug it with the android and java knowledge that i have, i could not able to fix what was the problem

Comment: [Come here for discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5098/android-people)

Comment: Sorry,First I could not able to find what was the problem ,how ever later to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of method for callback for menu selection is `onOptionsItemSelected()` instead of `onOptionsMenuSelected()`, try this way:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{
    //Your code implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my time, good troubleshooting. Keep it up friend

Comment: Make your Android project use 1.6 compiler settings and use @Override annotations. Then you get compile errors for such problems in the future. It is also advisable to always use code completion to overwrite a super method (because the name will be correct then).

Answer (score 0):

Is your Prefs activity in your manifest?

I might be wrong but I'll give a shot:
In line

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Prefs.class));
```

I think "this" does not represent your activity. Try create a static variable

```
static Activity thisActivity;
```

and on OnCreate

```
thisActivity = this;
```

then

```
startActivity(new Intent(thisActivity, Prefs.class));
```

Comment: 'this' should be valid...to start a new activity

Comment: anyway, I (almost) always use static variable instead of "this".

Comment: @mihail: I think, you haven't read the whole question. see the manifest.xml

Comment: would be much easier with a logcat :)